# Issue with Loading Module in PHPUnit for Testing: "Class Not Found" Error - Laminas

Tags: php, model-view-controller, service, laminas

I'm currently facing an issue with loading a module in PHPUnit for testing purposes. I have a module called "Candidat" in my Laminas (formerly Zend Framework) application, and I'm trying to write unit tests for it.

I've followed the recommended approach of setting up a separate PHPUnit test class and using the Laminas Test package. However, when I attempt to access the module's classes or services within the test class, I receive a "Class not found" error.

I have confirmed that the module is properly configured in my application and that the required class and namespace exist. I'm using Composer for autoloading, and I have already run composer update to ensure everything is up to date.

In my test class, I have used the setApplicationConfig() method to set the application configuration, including the necessary module configuration. However, when I try to access the module's classes or services using $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->get('Candidat\Service\CandidatService'), it throws a "Class not found" error.

I expected the test to be able to load the module and retrieve the required class or service without any issues. However, the actual result is the "Class not found" error.